# Can't find form on returned HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page consisting of a link and a div with id 'containerDiv'.
When you press the link it loads some HTML from another page using Ajax into this div.

The HTML that is returned contains a form. When the form is submitted, I wish to stay on the same page and display the resulting content in the div.

[Please see a picture showing what I wish to accomplish by clicking this link](http://servicebyen.dk/explanation.gif).

The script on the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            $('#containerDiv').load(this.href + ' #contentDiv', function () {
                alert($('#page2Form').id);
                $('#page2Form').submit(function () {
                    $.post(
                    pageName,
                    this.serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.success)
                            alert('done');
                        else
                            alert('error');
                        $('#containerDiv').html(data);
                    }
                );
                    return false;
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The relevant HTML on the main page:

```
<a id="link1" href="page1.aspx">Page 1</a>
    <br />
    <div id='console' style="border: 2px solid red; width: 1000px">
        when the link is clicked this content is replaced with new html.
    </div>
```

The relevant HTML on the content page:

```
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <form id="page2Form" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>
               Page 2</h1>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Submit_OnClick" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I can't find the form 'page2Form' on the returned HTML.

Alert ($('#page2Form'). id); returns 'undefined'

Perhaps it has something to do with that element is not loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here, jQuery objects won't have a `.id` property, you want the `id` of the first element in the matched set, like this:

```
alert($('#page2Form')[0].id);
//or without jquery:
alert(document.getElementById('page2Form').id);
```

Also, make sure you're looking for it *after* the `$('#containerDiv').html(data);` call, so it's added to the DOM. If you're looking for it *before* it's added, then use the returning `data` as the context to look in, like this:

```
alert($('#page2Form', data)[0].id);
```

Comment: alert($('#side2Form', data1)[0]);

Comment: @user484204 - Your code has `page2Form` your comment has `side2Form`...which is it? :)

Comment: @user484204 - Is it `data` or `data1`? That also changed.

Comment: $('#side2form').submit(function () {
                        $.post(
                        'side2form.aspx',
                        this.serialize(),
                        function (data) {
                            if (data.success)
                                alert('done');
                            else
                                alert('error');

                            $('#containerDiv').html(data);
                        });  
                        return false;
                    });

Comment: @user484204 - You're looking for the *element*, not the page load.

Comment: It looks like the form is submitted, but afterwords the new HTML is displayed on a separate page, instead of inside the container div as it should. See step 3 http://servicebyen.dk/explanation.gif

Comment: It looks like the callback function is not invoked. The 'done' or 'error' alert are not displayed.

Comment: @user484204 - are you getting a JavaScript error? it sounds like you're seeing default behavior kick in.

Comment: You are right. javescript error: This.serialize is not a function. I also tried this: $('#page2form')[0].serialize(), but I get the same error.

Comment: @user484204 -the `[0]` was for getting the ID, leave it off when calling `.serialize()` :)

Comment: Thanks, my problem is now that the alert('error') popup is triggered. The data object contains the html and data I have posted and not the expected data. Is data.success valid syntax?